# access the values of dict in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe `df` like below with one column events-

```
|events|
|{'id': 109421132110384, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 28, 11, 12, 50, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'in_reply_to_id': None, 'in_reply_to_account_id': None, 'sensitive': False, 'spoiler_text': '', 'visibility': 'public', 'language': 'en', 'uri': 'https://users/statuses/10942113190455'}|
|{'id': 109421132340384, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 30, 11, 12, 50, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'in_reply_to_id': None, 'in_reply_to_account_id': None, 'sensitive': False, 'spoiler_text': '', 'visibility': 'public', 'language': 'en', 'uri': 'https://users/statuses/10942113190467'}|
```

I tried below appraoch -

```
a= df['events'][0]
print(a['id'])
```

Getting error : TypeError: string indices must be integers

Datatypes returned-

```
print(type(df['events'][0])) 
<class 'str'>
print(type(df['events']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print(type(df))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

I want to access id,created_at,in_reply_to_id in new columns of the same dataframe for each respective records.

Please help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `print(a)` show?

Comment: Your 'Event' column is a string. It cannot be accessed as a dict.

Comment: @mcsoini, it prints - {'id': 109421132110384, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 28, 11, 12, 50, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'in_reply_to_id': None, 'in_reply_to_account_id': None, 'sensitive': False, 'spoiler_text': '', 'visibility': 'public', 'language': 'en', 'uri': 'https://users/statuses/10942113190455'}

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

Access the first element thanks to the `loc()` method.

Then access to the `event` column and finally to the `id` key of the dict.

```py
df.loc[0]["events"]["id"]  # 109421132110384
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.iloc()` to access the row and then specify the column name:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzutc
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"events": [
    {'id': 109421132110384, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 28, 11, 12, 50, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'in_reply_to_id': None, 'in_reply_to_account_id': None, 'sensitive': False, 'spoiler_text': '', 'visibility': 'public', 'language': 'en', 'uri': 'https://users/statuses/10942113190455'},
    {'id': 109421132340384, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 30, 11, 12, 50, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'in_reply_to_id': None, 'in_reply_to_account_id': None, 'sensitive': False, 'spoiler_text': '', 'visibility': 'public', 'language': 'en', 'uri': 'https://users/statuses/10942113190467'}
]})

print(df.iloc[0]["events"])
```

Output:

```
{'id': 109421132110384,
 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 28, 11, 12, 50, tzinfo=tzutc()),
 'in_reply_to_id': None,
 'in_reply_to_account_id': None,
 'sensitive': False,
 'spoiler_text': '',
 'visibility': 'public',
 'language': 'en',
 'uri': 'https://users/statuses/10942113190455'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 'Event' column is a printed representation of a dictionary, not a dictionary.

An ugly solution would be to map eval to create a new column. Make sure to import datetime first.

```
df['parsed_events'] = df['events'].map(eval)
```

Once parsed you can treat the contents as a dictionary.
Best would be to revisit how the original data was generated.

Here is an example...

```py
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzutc

string = "{'id': 109421132110384, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 28, 11, 12, 50, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'in_reply_to_id': None, 'in_reply_to_account_id': None, 'sensitive': False, 'spoiler_text': '', 'visibility': 'public', 'language': 'en', 'uri': 'https://users/statuses/10942113190455'}" 

eval(string)
```

produces the dictionary...

```py
{'id': 109421132110384,
 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 28, 11, 12, 50, tzinfo=tzutc()),
 'in_reply_to_id': None,
 'in_reply_to_account_id': None,
 'sensitive': False,
 'spoiler_text': '',
 'visibility': 'public',
 'language': 'en',
 'uri': 'https://users/statuses/10942113190455'}
```

Comment: I used import datetime - Getting error : File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined

Comment: @deepu2711 , I've added a code snippet to my answer